# How to select multiple items in Gridview with single swipe of finger in Android

Tags: android, uigesturerecognizer, swipe, gesture, gesture-recognition

I have a 4x4 Gridview in Android lollipop. When a user starts swiping his finger across I want to capture which cells are being swiped over. What event do I need to hook into?

Comment: I could guess what you are doing by looking at the tags you have applied to this question, but you need to put things into the question like platform, version, language, API you are using, etc. Don't make us guess. We may not guess correctly, and you will not get a good answer.

Comment: hello @stack would you found any solution to your problem. I am in need of something similar.